# Why is my constructor with non const reference as argument allowed to be called with temporary objects?

Tags: c++, most-vexing-parse

I have a sample code below.

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
class XYZ
{
   private:
   T & ref;
   public:
   XYZ(T & arg):ref(arg)
   {
   }
};
class temp
{
   int x;
   public:
   temp():x(34)
   {
   }
};
template<typename T>
void fun(T & arg)
{
}
int main()
{
   XYZ<temp> abc(temp());
   fun(temp());  //This is a compilation error in gcc while the above code is perfectly valid. 
}
```

In the above code even though XYZ constructor takes argument as non const reference, it compiles fine while the fun function fails to compile. Is this specific to g++ compiler or c++ standard has to say something about it?

Edit:

g++ -v gives this.

gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)

Comment: You should specify what version of g++ you're using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
 XYZ<temp> abc(temp());
```

It compiles, because it is NOT a *variable* declaration. I'm sure you think its a variable declaration when the fact is that its a *function* declaration. The name of the function is `abc`; the function returns an object of type `XYZ<temp>` and takes a single (unnamed) argument which in turn is a function returning type `temp` and taking no argument. See these topics for detail explanation:

- [The Most Vexing Parse](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=439) (at InformIT)
- [Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) (at wikipedia)

And  `fun(temp())` doesn't compile, because `temp()` creates a temporary object and a temporary object cannot be bound to non-const reference.

So the fix is this : define your function template as:

```
template<typename T>
void fun(const T & arg) //note the `const`
{
}
```

Comment: Nawaz, you are spot on. When I added another member function called memberFun and tried calling that using abc, I got the following error "temp.cpp:41:8: error: request for member ‘memberFun’ in ‘abc’, which is of non-class type ‘XYZ<temp>(temp (*)())."

Comment: @chappar: Exactly. `abc` is not an object of type `XYZ<temp>`. That is  why you cannot call any member function of `XYZ<temp>` using `abc`.

Answer (score 5):

No, the standard doesn't allow to pass a temporary to non const reference.  (C++0X introduced rvalue reference to allow this in some controlled cases), see 8.5.3/5 (which is too long for me to cite, the meaningful part is *otherwise, the reference shall be to a non-volatile const type*, but you have to read the whole list of cases to know that they don't apply here).

And

```
XYZ<temp> abc(temp());
```

is simply yet another example of the most vexing parse.

Comment: That answers half the question.